# How can I tell Resharper to allow underscore tolerant method names for a specific class in a test project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, naming-conventions

I like to write my tests using the current pattern:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest : TestContext
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.Given_a_mocked_logger();
        this.Given_a_system_under_test();

        this.When_getting_the_result();            
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_result_should_not_be_null()
    {
        Assert.NotNull(this.Result);
    }

// this class is always placed in it's own file in the same 
// test project as the above class
public class TestContext
{
    protected string Result;

    protected void Given_a_mocked_logger()
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected void Given_a_system_under_test()
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected void When_getting_the_result()
    {
        Result = "Whatever";
    }
}
```

However when using Resharper + Style Cop I get squiggly lines for the method names in both `MyTest` and `TestContext` classes, I managed to tell Resharper to allow Underscore tolerant naming conventions for all my test classes by following the instructions [HERE](http://atombrenner.blogspot.fr/2010/07/how-to-change-resharper-naming-style.html) however that solution does not cover the `TestContext` class as it does not fall under the `Test Type` nor the `Test Method`.

How can I tell Resharper to allow the above naming convention for all the `TestContext` classes in my Test projects without having to use Resharper comments to ignore inconsistent naming?

Comment: You know that the Setup Method will run for every test method you write. Your test method should contain 3 parts, Arrange, Act and Assert. You should also give these test metthods better names, something like: `UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior` http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html (according to Roy Osherove, he has a lot of good stuff on Unit Testing)

Comment: That's not correct, the method is flagged as `Test Fixture Setup` not `Test Setup` - Please note this is not a question on how to do TDD, this is an example for the problem that I have with Resharper naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may specify separate Naming Style settings for your Test project as described [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/01/18/per-project-settings-or-how-to-have-different-naming-styles-for-my-test-project/)

Answer (score 1):

Use these comments in your TestContext class:

```
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

...your code with "inconsistent" method names

// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I would like to avoid using comments.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. I hate them too, but in the end I found they didn't really get in the way of understanding the code, because they are outside of my methods.